# How do I flatten pixel layers in Affinity Designer?

Tags: layers, flatten, affinity-designer

Getting to grips with Affinity Designer by drawing a simple 16x16 pixel favicon, I've ended up with 5 pixel layers.  I'm looking for a "flatten" function to squash them back into a single layer but I not having any luck finding one - all the layer combination functions appear to be non-destructive.

There must be a way, mustn't there?  Please help!

Answer (score 5):

1. Add all layers in one group.
2. Right-click on this group (to get "context menu") and select **Rasterise...**

[image]

[image]

Comment: for reference: https://affinity.help/designer/en-US.lproj/index.html?page=/ObjectControl/rasterizing.html?title=Rasterizing

Answer (score 3):

Okay, so straight from the horses mouth - there is no "flatten" feature. Seems like a fairly basic operation to me!

"There isn't a merge command like in Photoshop, but as a workaround you can create a new empty layer, drag everything else to inside that layer and then go to Layer -> Rasterize..."

https://affinity.serif.com/forum/index.php?/topic/1147-merge-layers/

Comment: I guess it's because Affinity is fundamentally a vector app, and then has some pixel functionality on top of that.

Comment: True, but given that it supports pixel layers it would be nice if it allowed you to combine several into a single one, even if it doesn't want to allow you to render a vector layer.

Answer (score 0):

What I do in Affinity Designer is to select all the objects from the multiple layers I want to combine. (Hide all layers I'm not interested in, then select all with <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>). Then I group them <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd>), and immediately ungroup them (<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd>). They will end up in one layer, leaving the other ones empty.

I'm hoping this will be feature in future versions, although it seems like this has been an issue for a long time now.

Answer (score 0):

If there are 2 pixel layers. Select them both, group and then rasterize. The result is 1 pixel layer.

Answer (score -1):

1) Select each of the layers you want merged in the Layers panel.
2) Choose Layers -> Merge Selected or keyboard shortcut Ctrl-Shift-E.

Comment: I think you're talking about Affinity Photo, not Affinity Designer